# How to replace Activation layer of existing model in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a pretrained model which uses Swish (SiLU) activation:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0

e_net = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

I'd like to replace all it activations with LeakyReLU. For basic functions like ReLU or Sigmoid it can easly replaced like this:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation
from tensorflow.keras import activations

for layer in e_net.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, Activation):
        layer.activation = activations.get('relu')
```

But there is no LeakyRelu function in this module. Instead, it is implemented as separate layer and I have no idea how to replace it. Direct modification has no effect (even after recompiling model or saving/loading from file):

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU

for i, layer in enumerate(e_net.layers):
    if isinstance(layer, Activation):
        name = layer.name
        model.layers[i] = LeakyReLU(name=name) # does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to replace all the activations you are on the right path from the code snippet.
There is an issue with your code   `model.layers[i] = LeakyReLU(name=name)`. Using the name as a parameter will not work.
You can try the below code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
l_relu = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)

for layer in e_net.layers:
    if (hasattr(layer,'activation'))==True:
          layer.activation = l_relu
```

Cheers, hope it helps!

Comment: It worked, thanks :) `LeakyReLU(name=name)` also works, it just copies the replaced activation layer name.

Comment: Oh great, would be awesome if you could accept the answer! :)